# efficient way to detect periodicity of network flows

Tags: algorithm, period

I have lots of netflow data `(i.e src_ip, dest_ip, beg_time, end_time, data_size, etc)` and some of them are happening periodically that I want to find out.

Consider I have **n** netflow(maybe around 10^6) and **m** of them are **periodic**. How could I find which ones are periodic?

I can write a code but it will be at least O(n^3 logn), which will take forever for after 10^4 number of netflow.

I have searched about it but couldn't find anything.

Note: You can consider data is sorted according to start time and start time is 32 bit unsigned int(uint32 in c++)

**Correction**: `src_ip` is unique and `dest_ip` is not unique, `time for periodicity` is unknown. It may be 5 min or it may be 5 days. You can forget about `src_ip, dest_ip, end_time, data_size` and other attributes of flow. **I'm only looking for events whose beginning times are periodic** and you can consider, I have eleminated events which are unrelated like different src_ip's, and so on...

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: When you say "periodic", do you mean that the src_ip, and dest_ip are identical, and the `beg_time` is regular, like every 5 minutes or every three hours? You'll have to define what you mean by "periodic" here before you'll get anything like a reasonable answer.

Comment: So you want to identify messages by src_ip that have a regular interval? If one src_ip sends messages at time index 0, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 18, 20, 21, 25, 26, 27, 30, would you count those that are at 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, and 30 as periodic?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly my question. Now came to my mind but there may be more than one such periodic intervals, if possible, I want to find all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try computing FFT on signals corresponding to your data.

For example, I'd transform the chunk `beg_time`=1, `end_time`=5, `data_size`=100 into a square pulse from 1 to 5 units of time with the amplitude 100.

If you want analyze everything together, you superimpose all the pulses you've got.

If it doesn't make sense to put everything together, superimpose only the pulses from the same `src_ip` or from the same pair of `src_ip` and `dst_ip`.

And then run the FFT on those signals obtained through superposition and see if there any noticeable peaks in the frequency domain, or it all looks randomish, no outstanding peaks.

FFT runs in O(n*log(n)) time, where `n` is the number of signal samples.

I'm sure there must be better ways to do it, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: Look up Wikipedia. Learn to use Google. Get FFTW for C/C++.

Comment: Then learn FFT (or, strictly speaking, DFT and FT in general with its properties). Come one, you want someone else do all the work for you?